# aiohttp ClientSession error in get call: too many header bytes seen; overflow detected is returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

**Describe the bug**
When sending a call in a aiohttp ClientSession, the error `too many header bytes seen; overflow detected` is returned.

**To Reproduce**
No exact code to reproduce, because it uses proprietary sources. The code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

url = "https://url.com"
bodies = [{"body": 1}, {"body": 2}, {"body": 3}]

async def request(body, session):
    async with session.post(url, json=body) as resp:
        return await resp.json()
    #return await es_client.search(index=es_index, doc_type=es_doc_type, body=query)

async def msearch(bodies):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(request(body, session)) for body in bodies]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

results = loop.run_until_complete(msearch(bodies))
```

**Expected behavior**
This code should return a json response.

It is working for most calls, but if the result?/header?/...? of a call is getting to big, this message is thrown?

**Logs/tracebacks**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.virtualenvs/findme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 847, in start
    message, payload = await self._protocol.read()  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.virtualenvs/findme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 591, in read
    await self._waiter
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.virtualenvs/findme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 201, in data_received
    messages, upgraded, tail = self._parser.feed_data(data)
  File "aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx", line 523, in aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser.feed_data
aiohttp.http_exceptions.BadHttpMessage: 400, message='too many header bytes seen; overflow detected'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-25-8dd725416572>", line 11, in <module>
    results = loop.run_until_complete(msearch(bodies))
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<ipython-input-25-8dd725416572>", line 9, in msearch
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "<ipython-input-25-8dd725416572>", line 2, in request
    async with session.post(url, json=body) as resp:
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.virtualenvs/findme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.virtualenvs/findme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 504, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "/Users/stijngeuens/.virtualenvs/findme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 852, in start
    message=exc.message, headers=exc.headers) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400, message='too many header bytes seen; overflow detected', url=URL('https://url.com')
```

**Your version of the Python**

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 18 2019, 10:37:04)
```

**Your version of the aiohttp/yarl/multidict distributions**

```
aiohttp==3.6.2
yarl==1.3.0
multidict==4.5.2
```

**Additional context**
Running on Mac OS. Error both in Pycharm and Docker
Call is going to a local ES instance for development
Using the client library (ClientSession)

Answer (score 0):

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400, message='too many header bytes seen; overflow detected', url=URL('https://url.com')
```

This means that the server is replying with a [400 Bad Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) error, and the servers complaint is that headers are not formatted properly.

Based on the message, it's more likely than not the server is programmed in a manner that expects a certain amount of headers. The current request is sent with the following headers:

```py
{
    "Host": "example.com",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "User-Agent": "Python/3.8 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0",
    "Content-Length": "11",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
```

You can check this by:

```py
async def request(body, session):
    async with session.post(url, json=body) as resp:
        print(dict(resp.request_info.headers))
        return await resp.json()
```

I would check the server's documentation and see what exactly their `post` endpoint is expecting. If you are reverse-engineering some endpoint, I would recommend *also* copying the headers that the original request sent to the server. This will hopefully fix your issue.

I wasn't able to dig further into this because I'm assuming `url.com` is just a 'temporary' domain you placed in replacement for the original (understandably, if it's for privacy purpose).